# South does not create tables in correct database

Tags: django

I am using a database router for my tables in Django, but for some odd reason South keeps adding tables to the default database instead of the correct one. Does South not support routers? My app containing the models is named `backend`.

My settings.py:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['project.router.DatabaseAppsRouter']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'backend': 'darwin_evolution'}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'darwin_django',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'PORT': '8889',
    },
    'weblaege_conditions': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'darwin_evolution',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
      #  'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '8889',
    }
}
```

router.py:

from django.conf import settings

```
class DatabaseAppsRouter(object):
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models for different
    databases.

    In case an app is not set in settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING, the router
    will fallback to the `default` database.

    Settings example:

    DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'app1': 'db1', 'app2': 'db2'}
    """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """"Point all read operations to the specific database."""
        if settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.has_key(model._meta.app_label):
            return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """Point all write operations to the specific database."""
        if settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.has_key(model._meta.app_label):
            return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """Allow any relation between apps that use the same database."""
        db_obj1 = settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(obj1._meta.app_label)
        db_obj2 = settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(obj2._meta.app_label)
        if db_obj1 and db_obj2:
            if db_obj1 == db_obj2:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """Make sure that apps only appear in the related database."""
        if db in settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.values():
            return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(model._meta.app_label) == db
        elif settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.has_key(model._meta.app_label):
            return False
        return None
```

syncdb issue:

```
./manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 92, in handle_noargs
    syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 112, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 216, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 101, in create_permissions
    auth_app.Permission.objects.using(db).bulk_create(perms)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 356, in bulk_create
    self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 835, in _batched_insert
    using=self.db)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1511, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 899, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 176, in execute
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 92, in _warning_check
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: Data truncated for column 'name' at row 29
```

Comment: did you use the --database argument while creating the tables?

Comment: @SayanChowdhury, is there a procedure for this?

Comment: Try this:
./manage.py migrate <app_name> --database=weblaege_conditions

Comment: @SayanChowdhury, so i do the schemamigration as always and then use the `--database` when i migrate?

Comment: Yes, use --database when you migrate.

Comment: Strange. I am getting a error when i do syncdb. My model is functioning in django as we speak, and i am unable to backtrack this error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51091/discussion-between-sayan-chowdhury-and-javacake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reflect the changes in the database after schemamigration, you need to run

```
./manage.py migrate --database=weblaege_conditions
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases), it operates on the default database, but by providing a `--database` argument, you can create the tables in a different database.